# Remove ROI selections - ImageJ

Tags: tiff, imagej, roi

I received Tiff files with ROI marks on it, but without the corresponding ROI manager. I would like to remove the selections while preserving the original picture/background. Is there a convenient way to do so without selecting and removing each ROI selection individually?

I tried removing a selected field of the picture, but this resulted in removing the background instead

Comment: Not perfectly sure about the issue but if the RoIs are selections, you can remove all of them by "Edit >> Selection >> Select None". If however the RoIs are Overlays, you need to "Image >> Overlay >> Remove Overlay" or you may consider to simply not show the Overlays by "Image >> Overlay >> Hide Overlay".